# OLE Error Windows xp

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dll

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Delphi, ao executar somente nos computadores com o Windows XP estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
OLE error 80131513, ClassID: {3A8B6B96-4F23-4EB5-B4B1-243BFBC41A39}
```

Segue meu código:

```
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
     DM_Principal.pLarWS := CreateComObject(LarWS_TLB.CLASS_WS) as IWS;
  except on e : exception do
  begin
    showmessage('Erro: '+ e.message);
    //WinExec( 'regasm LarWS.dll /tlb:LarWS.tlb',SW_HIDE);
    //Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
    //Sleep(3000);
    //Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    //DM_Principal.pLarWS := CreateComObject(LarWS_TLB.CLASS_WS) as IWS;
  end;
  end;
```

Segue o código do [LARWS_TLB](https://pastebin.com/sKrzWwJ4).

Já atualizei o .NET Framework para a versão 4.0.3. O estranho é que conforme já mencionado esse problema ocorre somente em computadores com Windows XP.

Comment: Não sei se é o seu caso dê uma lida neste artigo:
http://www.flexdocs.com.br/suporte/knowledgebase.php?article=215

Comment: Sei que não é uma resposta, mas tenho alguns clientes com Windows desatualizado que sempre apresentam algum tipo de problema, e nesses casos recomendo atualizarem para um mais recente. O XP já tem quase 20 anos.